# Hide value of Multipart Option Form - Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this template of Vue

```
<select v-model="newPsu" class="form-control-psu" multiple="true" name="psuDropdown" id="psuDropdown" size="10" style="max-height: 100px">
   <option v-if="level>= 1" v-for="option in provinsiOptions" v-bind:value="option.text">
        {{ option.text }}
   </option>
   <option v-if="level>= 2" v-for="option in kabupatenOptions" v-bind:value="option.text">
        {{ option.text }}
   </option>
</select>
```

I wanna hide option value from multipart from if another v-if is selected.

For now, if I choose level>2 after level>1. Value of level 1 is still shown in the form.

Comment: In reality, I don't do that way since I think it is bad code. Instead, You should split into small `component` and have a function validation to check what data to pass as props which depend on `level` from parent. this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Well currently you are saying if level is 1 and higher than 1 show. I think you meant to say this https://jsfiddle.net/cckLd9te/4655/?

```
<select v-model="newPsu" multiple="true">
      <option v-if="level == 1">Level 1</option>
      <option v-if="level > 1" v-for="option in provinsiOptions" v-bind:value="option.text">
        {{ option.text }}
      </option>
      <option v-if="level > 2" v-for="option in kabupatenOptions" v-bind:value="option.text">
        {{ option.text }}
      </option>
     </select>
```

Comment: No, i mean if i choose level>1, that will shown level>1. After that i choose level>2, that should shown just level>2. But for now, both of them will shown. I wanna shown either.

Comment: Why dont you `level == 1` and `level == 2`?